# Is it right to be using git push in this situation

Tags: git

I am on a feature branch **fluffy**. I have made some changes on **fluffy** that I know should be on **master**. I checkout **master** then cherry pick the change from **fluffy**. I then checkout **fluffy** and rebase on **master**. Everything is now cool. **fluffy** is ahead of **master** and the cherry picked changes are on the tip of **master**

However now I try

```
git push origin fluffy
```

from the **fluffy** branch. I am warned this is not a fast forward. My normal inclincation is just to

```
git push -f origin fluffy
```

and force it.

The general question is. Is there a workflow to cherry pick framework changes back to master from the feature branch, keeping the history without merge bubbles and not have to do a forced push to origin with my feature branch when it is all done.